# Why ClassException with Interface adapter Activity?

Tags: android, exception, android-activity, interface, adapter

I am trying to use an item button in listview, and tell activity button has been clicked
I have an exception : java.lang.ClassCastException: com.nhippye.curve.curve cannot be cast to com.nhippye.curve.roadListPackage.roadListMainActivity

```
    //public class roadListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<roadListItem> implements Filterable
```

```
    private Context mContext;
```

```
    public roadListAdapter(Context context, List<roadListItem> roads) 
    {
    super(context, R.layout.road_row_item, roads);
    this.roads = roads;
    this.context = context;
    filterList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.filterList.addAll(roads);
    this.mContext = context; 
    }
```

```
    Button ButtonViewRoadListItemMenu = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonRoadListItemMenu);
    ButtonViewRoadListItemMenu.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
    ((roadListMainActivity)mContext).myAction(); // CLASS EXCEPTION
    }
    });
```

```
    //public class roadListMainActivity extends  AppCompatActivity implements   View.OnFocusChangeListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener
    { //...
    public void  myAction()
    {
    // do something here
    Log.d("$$myAction ", "myAction");
    }
    }
```

Comment: How do you instantiate `roadListAdapter `? What type of context did you pass to its constructor?

Comment: adapter = new roadListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), roadListItems);

Comment: Application context cannot be cast to Activity. For UI stuff you won't need Application context, use Activity context instead.

Comment: YES! it works, i changed getApplicationContex to "this". Hours and hours of pain, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can get the activity context from the clicked view:

```
((roadListMainActivity) view.getContext()).myAction();
```

Also I suggest you follow naming standards and have Uppercase class names and lowercase names for its instances.

Comment: Still have  java.lang.ClassCastException: com.nhippye.curve.curve cannot be cast to com.nhippye.curve.roadListPackage.roadListMainActivity